# error with saveVideo R package animation

Tags: r, animation, ffmpeg

I'm doing an animation with R, and its working. However i cannot save it as video. I tried everything with saveVideo and get this error:
sh: ffmpeg: command not found
Error in system(paste(ffmpeg, "-version"), intern = TRUE) : 
  error in running command

I died everything the documentation says and nothing

```
saveVideo({
```

for (i in 1:100){
    tst <- read.csv(paste("RES_job",i,".csv",sep=""),header=F)

```
x <- tst$V1
y <- tst$V2
x1 <- tst$V3
y1 <- tst$V4
cc <- tst$V6[1]
sr <- tst$V7[1]
par(mar = rep(4, 4))
plot(x,y,pch=46, xlab="Females", ylab="Males",frame.plot=F,
     main=paste("Mode = P-M" , "cc = ", cc , "OSR = ", sr))
Arrows(x,y,x1,y1,arr.length = 0.15,lwd=2,arr.width = 0.1, 
       arr.adj=1, arr.type = "curved")
ani.pause(0.1)
```

}
},video.name = "test_png.mp4", other.opts = "-b 1000k")

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg installed? Note the system requirements listed here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html

Comment: Oh it worked. Yes, I did had it installed, but I save it before in .gif and apparently changed some path. I just restarted R again and that did the trick :)